# Speeding up PHP Include\Require Function

Tags: php, include, require

I have a program that I have been building for a while, and it is quite big (a large number of files). The Bootstrap process alone has `130 .php files` minimum, and `160` maximum. On my local system, it takes about `1ms` to `require`a a file, and on my production server, that is down to `200us`, but this means that on the production server, before the app even starts, it is taking `30ms` to get the app running.

The number of files cannot really be distilled down any more, but I am working on a merging program that would strip it down to about `80` files, but that's still a while.

The production & development machines have APC installed on them. If I change the server, I could create a ramdisk partition with a start up script to move and maintain the code base. Ideally, that is what I would like to do, but I am looking for a way that could be applied without having to get a VPS (or a web host who does this already), so what else could I try? Are there any libraries that speed up the file loading?

Comment: Are all the files always needed? You could use lazy loading so you only pull the files needed.

Comment: I do, the 130 files are the absolute minimum of files that the system requires to run. The 30 after that are specified functionality

Comment: How about creating a script that merges everything in one file for the production server? You could also strip whitespace this way

Comment: Well, that's something I'm trying at the moment. Ensuring that any files that can merge, are merged. I am going to merge some files, then set up a variable within the File that declares what this collection represents singularly (which is what it does atm). But a build script would be good to do that to all areas that are affected. How much performance does the whitespace add usually to the processing time?

Comment: did you tried [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: @bystwn22 yup, i used that at first, but it did nothing for speed, but dramatically simplified loading new libraries (especially on an as needed basis, but my code did that already)

Comment: If your files are a library and don't do anything by themselves, you can combine them into one large file and `php_strip_whitespace` it when done. It's the best you can do. `Autoload` would be another solution if you have classes. If you have functions... it ain't gonna work.